# Listing contents of Evernote trash

Tags: java, sdk, evernote, recycle-bin

How does one list the contents the trash in the current Evernote account using the Evernote Java SDK? I have attempted to list the contents of Notebook "Trash" by calling method findNotes() of the NoteStoreClient to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `inactive` to True in [NoteFilter](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Struct_NoteFilter) when you call [NoteStore#findNotesMetadata](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_findNotesMetadata) (I think findNotes is deprecated). See [this doc](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/searching_notes.php) as well.